# Latex Tikz externalize with shell escape does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, memory

Im trying to use the Tikz externalize, because for some tikz pictures the file gets to big and exceeds the memory size. I found a lot of other topics with similar problems, but non of the solutions worked for me or I did not implement them well enough. 
I'm using Winedt 10.2(also tried Winedt 9)
Mixtex 2.9

The structure of the report:

```
Final_Report.tex
--Layout.tex
--Simulation_model.tex
----plot_baseunit.tex(Tikz picture)
```

Final_Report.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\input{./Lay_out/layout.tex}`
\begin{document}
\input{./Chapters/Simulation_Model/Simulation_Model.tex}
\end{document}
```

layout.tex

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows,fit,positioning,shapes,chains, plotmarks,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc,patterns,angles,quotes,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/,shell escape=-enable-write18]
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
%Standard figure dimension
\newcommand{\plotx}{12.0cm}
\newcommand{\ploty}{6.0cm}
\newcommand{\plotysub}{3.0cm} %y-dimension of seperate subplots
%Subplot dimensions (2 plots wide subplots)
\newcommand{\subtwoplotx}{5.25cm}
\newcommand{\subtwoploty}{4.5cm}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, node distance=2.0cm, minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=2.0cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
```

Simulation_model.tex

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\input{./figures/plot_baseunit.tex}
}%
\caption{The throughput and cycle time of the production line plotted against the process time of a base unit workstation, as bottleneck of the system. The horizontal dotted lines represent the designed throughput and cycle time of the Honda/JLR(green) and Audi/Porsche roof systems(purple).}
\label{fig:Base_unit_through}
\end{figure}
```

When I try to run this using PDFTeXify it gives the following error.

```
   (figures/plot_baseunit.tex
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname 
"figures/Final_Report-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Final_Report}\input{Final_Report}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error-interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "figures/Final_Report-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob
{Final_Report}\input{Final_Report}" 
did NOT result in a usable output file 
'figures/Final_Report-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). 
Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
 Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe  the command simply failed?
 Error messages can be found in 'figures/Final_Report-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

If I just press enter the right figures come out, but this does not work for large files and then the memory size is exceeded.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Start with a simple example that doesn't involve subfolders and subfiles. When this work you can go on.

Comment: Have you really enabled system calls aka shell escapes (see the error message)?

Comment: The shell calls go into your editor, not the document you write. If you have problems with cumulative Tikz pictures exceeding the memory, try commenting all and uncomment once at a time. The pdf that is included with tikzexternalize take little to no TeX capacity, so on each run you only have a tikz picture to compile.

Comment: @Schweinebacke:  Sorry, I read too hastily. Thanks for pointing the sentence. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: How did you configure WinEdt to add `-shell-escape` (or `--enable-write18`) to the switches of `pdflatex`?

Comment: Personally, I've never gotten TikZ externalize to work either.  I just use a separate build with standalone.  Frankly, externalize will never be as efficient as doing it as a separate step.

Comment: @ Bernard. I dont know that, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tried that, still the same problem

Comment: Fine.  Then you should be able to shorten your question and remove all the irrelevant parts. Beside this: Go in winedt to `options - execution modes - pdflatex` and add `--shell-escape` in the field switches. Then compile with pdflatex (not texify!).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Presumably you haven't really tried because you prefer another method :-). It works straightforwardly enough. It is less efficient in some ways, potentially more efficient in others. But it is the other advantages which really favour externalisation for me, such as automatically ensuring consistency with the rest of the document (fonts, colours etc.).

Comment: @ UlrikeFischer. Your solution worked for most of the tikz (<100KB) but for the one of 1MB the memory is exceeded. I first try to expand this one, but then the buffer size was to small. Is there something going wrong in the externinalize, or is the file just to big?(QQplot of 100000 points)